# Some material icons are not displayed like login/start material icons

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-icon

i'm using angular material Icons (v14) and find out that some icons are not displayed in my project.
example of working mat-icon :
`<mat-icon fontIcon="home"></mat-icon>`

exemple of not working mat-icon :
`<mat-icon fontIcon="login"></mat-icon>`
or this one : `<mat-icon fontIcon="start"></mat-icon>` that shows me **star** icon instead of **start** one .
Also, I changed directly the value of material icon tag in the HTML source code (Chrome inspect tool) with correspondig icon name to confirm that it is related to some icons between others..
`<mat-icon _ngcontent-eet-c388="" role="img" class="mat-icon notranslate material-icons mat-ligature-font mat-icon-no-color" aria-hidden="true" data-mat-icon-type="font">star</mat-icon>`

is there any one who faced the same issue ? Can't find an explanation of this behavior...

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Even though its not what the documentation says, I've been using home and that works.

I have no idea why the documentation tells you to specify the fontIcon attribute, which I have not be able to get to work either.